# How to make a script connect and and run some command to EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu-16.04

I successfully connected to EC2 already, but when it connects, what is in my script run on my computer and not in the instance.

```
ssh -i key.pem  -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@XXXXX
echo "Hello World" # run on my computer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it this way

```
ssh -i key.pem  -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@XXXXX 'bash -s' < your_script.sh
```

and have a local file `your_script.sh` with all the command you want to run on the ec2 instance

Comment: I think a -t flag is necessary to keep on sessoon